# (GNU) Make: How does one set up a basic system?

Tags: build, makefile, gnu-make

I would like to try to establish a very small system of Makefiles.  I have the following set up, but something is not quite right (this has been pieced together from reading a few SO posts about the topic, though somewhat project-specific, and some websites.  I must not be catching something fundamental in having a "Makefile" call sub-makefiles.

This is even simpler than having the main Makefile call files in different subdirectories.  Here are the following files I have prepared:

Makefile:

```
all:
    $(MAKE) -f ./make_system.mk
    $(MAKE) -f ./make_crc.mk
```

make_system.mk:

```
G  = -g      ## debug option
CC = gcc     ## compiler
SRCS = source.c sink.c gateway.c
EXES = source sink gateway
OBJS = source.o sink.o gateway.o
CFLG = 
LFLG =
LIB = #-lsocket -lnsl -lpthread
```

all: $(EXES)

%.o: %.c %.h
    $(CC) -c $G $(CFLG) $<

source: source.o
    $(CC) -o source source.o $(LIB) $(LFLG)

sink: sink.o
    $(CC) -o sink sink.o $(LIB) $(LFLG)

gateway: gateway.o
    $(CC) -o gateway gateway.o $(LIB) $(LFLG)

clean:
    /bin/rm -f core *.o $(EXES) *~

make_crc.mk:

```
CC     = gcc
CFLAGS = -g
LFLAGS =
HDR    = crcmode.h
SRC    = crcmodel.c crctest.c
OBJ    = crcmodel.o crctest.o
EXE    = crctest
```

all: $(EXE)

%.o: %.c %.h
    $(CC) -c $(CLFAGS) $<

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $(EXE)

clean:
    /bin/rm -f *.o *~ core $(EXE)

How would I set up Makefile to call the smaller sub-makefiles (of type *.mk)?  This is a basic but important first step towards working with larger scale makefile systems (there is the manual to consult, though I do not think it has explicit basic examples).  If someone who has done this could show me a small Makefile vignette, this would be greatly appreciated (again, this makefile system can exist within the same local directory).

Note:  The individual makefiles "make_system" and "make_crc" work fine when they are themselves named "Makefile", but I want to try to call them as separate sub-makefiles with one single overall Makefile.

ADDENDUM (to solution below):
Once I implemented Carl's solution shown below, I realized that you need to always include some form of "make clean" or at least enter at in the command line before calling your Makefile.  Otherwise, you see the appropriate output "nothing to be done".  This was something I knew before, but neglected to do this time around (easy check:  just look at your directory and you will see you have executables in the environment/directory).

Comment: What's the problem you're having?  That looks ok to me.

Comment: When you say "The individual makefiles ... work fine when they are themselves named "Makefile", but", do you mean they don't work when invoked as "make -f make_system.mk" and "make -f make_crc.mk"?

Comment: I've updated my post above so you can see the output I get.  It doesn't seem to be working when I type in a label "all" even though is in both sub-makefiles.  I chose to rename each submakefile from "Makefile" (as they each were originally called) to "some_descriptive_name.mk" and then title the new main makefile "Makefile".  And I did type "make clean" before executing this new system of makes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you want to "forward" the target, you'll need to do it explicitly.  Something like this example should work (though I can't test easily right now, sorry):

```
default: all 
%:
    $(MAKE) -f ./make_system.mk $@
    $(MAKE) -f ./make_crc.mk $@
```

Comment: I get the following upon doing that in the main Makefile (exactly what is in your post is what is in the main Makefile) as you propose:
<code> $ make  Makefile:2: *** missing separator.  Stop. </code>
Does something go after the @ symbol?

Comment: That usually means you have spaces instead of tabs in your recipe.

Comment: Just fixed it so there were no tabs (as you are correct, GNUmake treats tabs differently).  Still same error.

Comment: No, there need to *be* tabs.

Comment: You're right, grave syntax error on my part.  Well, I now have the main makefile as you posted and get this:
"$ make   make: *** No targets.  Stop."

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if that will work, but you get the idea.  You need a real target as well as the %.  Should be easy enough to work out from there.  Next time I get to a real computer I'll try a quick test.

Comment: Agreed, and upon fixing it, we have now reached the error I put at the bottom of my original post.  Is there something else I need to configure my main Makefile with, such as something following the @ symbol?  Most examples I find are complicated and don't get the simple point across of how one Makefile calls the other makefiles.  I don't need anything fancy, just the simple structure that allows one Makefile to call *.mk's.

Comment: There don't seem to be any errors in that block at the end of your post.

Comment: Ah, fixed it.  It was as simple as entering "$ make clean" at the command line and then recalling the primary makefile again.  And yes, I was abusing the word "error", I was just confused as to why it was not re-making anything (originally, "make clean" did not work, but now that combined with your solution, the system works).  Thank you!